# Why all Flow types in my VueJs files ('*.vue') are underlined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, flowtype

I installed Flow packages according to this instructions: https://flow.org/en/docs/install/

That's how types are shown in my VueJs ('*.vue') files write now. I don't know, why but they are all underlined:

[image]

[image]

**Is there a way fix that?**

In my ordinary ".js" files 'Flow' works fine:

[image]

Comment: This is most likely done by your editor and/or syntax coloring/theme. What editor and theme packages are you using?

Comment: @FeifanZ I am using 'phpStorm', Intellij theme.

Comment: @FeifanZ I found that in '*.vue' files Flow doesn't work with interfaces as should. He doesn't show any warnings messages if there is any mistake in  the interface realization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're [using PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740394/why-all-flow-types-in-my-vuejs-files-vue-are-underlined?noredirect=1#comment76462301_44740394), it looks like you should install the Vue.js plugin: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/vue-js.html

> Before you start, install and enable the Vue.js plugin. The plugin is not bundled with PhpStorm, but it can be installed from the JetBrains plugin repository …. That is all, no additional configuration is required to have all Vue.js-related features work in any project

Comment: It was installed. Conclusion: - That is not the cause of the problem. Thank you for you reply!